# how to generate RGBA4444 texture data using libpng, and use it for opengl?

Tags: android, opengl-es, libpng, rgba

i'm working on a android game, now my picture files are all "rgba8888" png files, my current work flow is using libpng to analyze those picture files as  "rgba8888" format into a chunk of data, then generate RGBA8888 textures for opengl(through glTexImage2D function),

now i want to use RGBA4444 color format to reduce the memory cost, and my questions are:

1. how do i convert my rgba8888 png files to rgba4444 format?(i originally thought a simple export option in PS will do it, but negative)
2. does libpng support rgba4444 format??and how do i analyze it in general? if not, what should i do?

Answer (score 1):

Libpng doesn't support RGBA4444.  It does, however, support user transforms, so it should be possible to write a user callback function to transform your RGBA8888 pixels to RGBA4444 pixels that would be returned to your app.

Search the file "libpng_manual.txt" that is distributed with libpng for "user_transform_fn".  For an example of a working user transform function, look a the source for pngcrush, search for "pngcrush_transform_pixels_fn".